# Caliburn.Micro - Wrap Model or expose it directly?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm currently facing one of the most discussed problems in MVVM: I have a complex Model in my WPF application and I'm not sure how I should display its data to the View.

According to many answers here on StackOverflow and also to [this article](http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx) there are two ways:

1. to wrap the Model inside the ViewModel by adding a property in the ViewModel for each property in the Model
2. to expose the Model directly to the view without replicating the properties.

What I understood so far is that the first approach is better from a theoretical point of view, while the second one is a quick shortcut that should be avoided.

In the [same article](http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx) I previously linked, the author writes the following:

> In reviewing the sample application from the Caliburn framework, they implement the VM using option 2.

I took a look at the Caliburn.Micro documentation and unfortunately it just uses a simple ViewModel without a real Model, so I don't know how to verify this statement.

Is the author right? Since I'm using Caliburn.Micro should I use the second approach instead of the first one in order to be more "compliant" with the framework implementation?

Comment: Ultimately, do what you want. There's various levels of how 'strict' you follow the conventions. What your budget constraints, timescales, project size, company processes and personal preference is more important than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I'm using Caliburn.Micro should I use the second approach instead of the first one in order to be more "compliant" with the framework implementation?

No. Caliburn.Micro is just an MVVM library. *How* you implement the actual MVVM pattern is entirely up to you.

I agree with @Marek Dzikiewicz that you should wrap the model in a view model class that may implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and provide any other UI specific functionality. This code doesn't belong to a business object. You could refer to my answer here for more information:

[Reuse the same models in ASP.NET MVC and WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506055/reuse-the-same-models-in-asp-net-mvc-and-wpf-mvvm/41521828#41521828)

Obviously if the model class is indeed a UI specific class that is not used in any other application and doesn't contain any business logic that is used on the server side, you could modify this class and bind to it directly. But then it is kind of a (sub) view model after all.

Comment: I asked [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44528570/2827454). Maybe having (sub) viewmodels can be useful if you have a requirement to implement similar UI screens in WPF and MVC and you would like to share user input validation logic for example? Being client specific sub-viewmodels can be exposed directly to Views as a Model property. Does it worth a hassle? Probable downside that implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged has no use for MVC. I think I was not clear in my original question (it was down-voted :)). Can it be closed as duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is better to expose view models because that allows you to add additional properties to control the way the data is displayed (for example formatting or concatenating data). However, if you don't need that, there is nothing wrong in exposing the model classes directly.